# CSS overriding/ignoring 'display:inline-grid' on media query for small screens

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with a frontend blog website prototype template. It contains five main divs - a top nav bar, a "window" for the blog's banner image, profile photo and blog name, "blogPosts" containing posts from the user floated to the left with `'display:inline-block'` set, "sidePosts" floated to the right for recent and popular posts with `'display:inline-block'`, then a "NavBar" div at the bottom of the page.

I updated the CSS so by default it uses `'display:inline-grid'` for both the blogPosts and SidePosts, changing to `'display:inline-block'` when the screen is bigger than 600 pixels, but the divs still default to a floated side by side view. Chrome debugging shows that the `'display:inline-block'` overrides `'display:grid'` for whatever reason. Same issue when I use grid instead of inline-grid. Originally I had a div `id` called `#BlogPosts` whilst the individual posts were kept in a `class` called `.blogPost`, so I renamed this to `.post` after seeing Zuber's comment to see if that would fix the issue, but it made no difference. Any advise on how to fix this?

`````css
//classes set first

.page{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 height:100%;
}

.post{
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 //removed background color to improve visual design
    //background-color:#e0e1e2;
    margin-left:6%;
 margin-bottom:1%;
    max-width:100%;
    border-radius:1%;
 right:none;
}

.post h1{
    margin-bottom:none;
    padding-bottom:none;
}

.post2{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 //removed background color to improve visual design
    //background-color:#e0e1e2;
    margin-left:6%;
 margin-bottom:1%;
    max-width:85%;
    border-radius:1%;
 right:none;
}

.post2 a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}

.pageNav{
 bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:1.2em;
}

.pageNav p{
 display:inline;
}

.pageNav a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}

#blogPosts{
 display:grid;
}

#SidePosts{
 display:grid;
}

//set color to blue to debug if media query active
body{
 background-color:lightblue;
}

/*
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
 
 #blogPosts{
  display:inline-grid;
 }
 
 #SidePosts{
  display:inline-grid;
 }
 
}
*/

@media screen and (max-width:2000px){
 
.page{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 height:100%;
}
 
body{
 background-color:white;
}

#window{
 width:100%;
 max-width:100%;
 min-height:40%;
 text-align:center;
}

#banner{
 position:relative;
 min-width:100%;
 max-width:100%;
 //min-height:20%;
 height:25.5em;
 object-fit:cover;
 z-index:1;
}

#avatar{
 position:absolute;
 max-width:10%;
 bottom:33%;
 left:45.5%;
 z-index:2;
 border-style:solid;
}

#window h1{
 position:relative;
 margin-top:5%;
 margin-left:1%;
}

#blogPosts{
 display:inline-grid;
 display:block;
 width:60%;
 float:left;
 margin-left:4%;
}

#SidePosts{
 //display:inline-grid;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 background-color: #e0e1e2;
 width:28%;
 padding-left:2%;
 margin-right:2%;
 margin-bottom:2%;
 border-radius:4%;
}

#SidePosts a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}

#sidePosts h1{
 margin-top:none;
}

/* Code taken from W3Schools for nav bar.*/

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
````display:grid;
    grid-column: 1 / 12;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Style the "active" element to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: white;
}

/* Style the search box inside the navigation bar */
.topnav input[type=text] {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600px wide, stack the links and the search field vertically instead of horizontally 
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a, .topnav input[type=text] {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 14px;
    }
    .topnav input[type=text] {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
}
*/

}
`````

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<Html>

<!--Header loads CSS page and sets title-->
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="blogStyle.css">
 <title>Blog.</title>
</head>

<body>

<!--Page Div acts as container for all page elements-->
<div class="page">

<!--topnav taken from W3Schools and modified-->
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="">Blog.</a>
  <a href=""id="login">Login</a>
  <!--<a href="#contact">Register</a>
  <a href="">Top</a>
  <a href="">Recent</a>-->
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="searchBar"> <!--added this element to template-->
</div>

<div id="window">
 <!--<img style="width:100%;height:400px;object-fit:cover;"src="paul-gilmore-181002-unsplash.jpg">-->
 <!--<img style="max-width:15%;max-height:15%;z-index:2;align:center;"src="avatar.jpg" border="2">-->
 
 <img id="banner"src="paul-gilmore-181002-unsplash.jpg">
 <img id="avatar"src="spike-avatar.jpg">
 <h1>Joe's Blog</h1>
</div>

<div id="blogPosts">

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

</div>

<div id="SidePosts">
<h1><a href="">Recent</a></h1>

<div class="post2">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>User: John</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post2">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>User: John</i></h4>
</div>

<h1><a href="">Popular</a></h1>

<div class="post2">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>User: John</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post2">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>User: John</i></h4>
</div>

</div>

</div>

<!--Each a link in pageNav would link to previous page of blog, first page, last page and next page-->
<div class="pageNav">
 <a href=""><</a>
 <a href="">1</a>
 <p>...</p>
 <a href="">25</a>
 <a href="">></a>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using same name `blogPosts` for `id` and `class` in `css`, and you have set different `css` for them. maybe that is creating problem for you

Comment: I have a div `id` named `#blogPosts` containing all the posts, whilst the individual posts themselves are named as `.blogPost`. They have different names so that shouldn't be causing an issue, but I'll try renaming the `.blogPost` class to `.post`.

Comment: Some of your css is commented with `//` are you running it like this?

Comment: If you uncomment it, it will still be overriden by your 2000px media query  (which is block - as you override the grid immediately) - either move it to the end or change your other media query to be between 600 and 2000

Comment: Your `<head>` element is missing the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` declaration. This could be the reason why Chrome doesn't apply the media query for <600px and treats the layout as ~980px layout zoomed out to the window width, as many mobile devices do by default (details here: https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html).

Comment: Noted guys, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution after being stuck on this issue for many hours! I fixed it by changing the way the CSS is structured - many of the CSS styles are now set by default for mobile screens, including the `display:grid` setting for the blog post container divs, then styling is applied afterwards for larger screens using the media query `@media screen and (min-width:700px)`. Changing `max` to `min` made the code work. You can find the updated site below:

`````css
//classes set first

/* Code taken from W3Schools for nav bar.*/

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation bar */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
````display:grid;
    grid-column: 1 / 12;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Style the "active" element to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: white;
}

/* Style the search box inside the navigation bar */
.topnav input[type=text] {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600px wide, stack the links and the search field vertically instead of horizontally 
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a, .topnav input[type=text] {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 14px;
    }
    .topnav input[type=text] {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
}
*/

.page{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 height:100%;
}

.post{
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 //removed background color to improve visual design
    //background-color:#e0e1e2;
    margin-left:6%;
 margin-bottom:1%;
    max-width:100%;
    border-radius:1%;
 right:none;
}

.post h1{
    margin-bottom:none;
    padding-bottom:none;
}

.post2{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 //removed background color to improve visual design
    //background-color:#e0e1e2;
    margin-left:6%;
 margin-bottom:1%;
    max-width:85%;
    border-radius:1%;
 right:none;
}

.post2 a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}

.pageNav{
 bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:1.2em;
}

.pageNav p{
 display:inline;
}

.pageNav a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}

body{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#window{
 width:100%;
 max-width:100%;
 min-height:40%;
 text-align:center;
}

#banner{
 position:relative;
 min-width:100%;
 max-width:100%;
 //min-height:20%;
 height:15.5em;
 object-fit:cover;
 z-index:1;
}

#avatar{
 position:absolute;
 max-width:15%;
 bottom:52%;
 left:43.5%;
 z-index:2;
 border-style:solid;
}

#window h1{
 position:relative;
 margin-top:5%;
 margin-left:1%;
}

#blogPosts{
 display:grid;
}

#SidePosts{
 display:grid;
 background-color: #e0e1e2;
 border-radius:5%;
}

#SidePosts a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 margin-left:4%;
 font-size:0.8em;
}

//set color to blue to debug if media query active
body{
 background-color:lightblue;
}

/*
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
 
 #blogPosts{
  display:inline-grid;
 }
 
 #SidePosts{
  display:inline-grid;
 }
 
}
*/

@media screen and (min-width:700px){
 
body{
 background-color:white;
}

#blogPosts{
 display:inline-grid;
 display:block;
 width:60%;
 float:left;
 margin-left:4%;
}

#SidePosts{
 //display:inline-grid;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 width:28%;
 padding-left:2%;
 margin-right:2%;
 margin-bottom:2%;
}

#sidePosts h1{
 margin-top:none;
}

#banner{
 height:25.5em;
}

#avatar{
 position:absolute;
 max-width:10%;
 bottom:28%;
 left:45.5%;
 z-index:2;
 border-style:solid;
}

}
`````

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<Html>

<!--Header loads CSS page and sets title-->
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="blogStyle.css">
 <title>Blog.</title>
</head>

<body>

<!--Page Div acts as container for all page elements-->
<div class="page">

<!--topnav taken from W3Schools and modified-->
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="">Blog.</a>
  <a href=""id="login">Login</a>
  <!--<a href="#contact">Register</a>
  <a href="">Top</a>
  <a href="">Recent</a>-->
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="searchBar"> <!--added this element to template-->
</div>

<div id="window">
 <!--<img style="width:100%;height:400px;object-fit:cover;"src="paul-gilmore-181002-unsplash.jpg">-->
 <!--<img style="max-width:15%;max-height:15%;z-index:2;align:center;"src="avatar.jpg" border="2">-->
 
 <img id="banner"src="paul-gilmore-181002-unsplash.jpg">
 <img id="avatar"src="spike-avatar.jpg">
 <h1>Joe's Blog</h1>
</div>

<div id="blogPosts">

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>2nd January 2012,3:34PM</br>
 Random, Productivity, Music</i></h4>
</div>

</div>

<div id="SidePosts">
<h1><a href="">Recent</a></h1>

<div class="post2">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>User: John</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post2">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>User: John</i></h4>
</div>

<h1><a href="">Popular</a></h1>

<div class="post2">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>User: John</i></h4>
</div>

<div class="post2">
 <h3>Post Title</h3>
 <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultrices blandit erat sed fermentum. Sed scelerisque lacus et condimentum congue.Morbi eu purus id mauris lobortis bibendum. Praesent nec placerat mi. Maecenas sodales fermentum turpis a vehicula. tincidunt aliquam just.</h4>
 <h5><i>User: John</i></h4>
</div>

</div>

</div>

<!--Each a link in pageNav would link to previous page of blog, first page, last page and next page-->
<div class="pageNav">
 <a href=""><</a>
 <a href="">1</a>
 <p>...</p>
 <a href="">25</a>
 <a href="">></a>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```